# Ingesting Firebase Realtime Database JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to parse JSON coming in from a Firebase Realtime Database instance, and display it in a table.

I can return the JSON from the URL and store it in PHP but I can't seem to get it to display.

The JSON Output looks like this:

```
{"\"1\"":{"itemDescription":"This is a description of the item.","itemName":"Item Name","itemValue":{"costAmount":200,"costType":"dol"}},"\"2\"":{"itemDescription":"This is an item description.","itemName":"Item Name 2","itemValue":{"costAmount":500,"costType":"dol"}}}
```

In PHP I am doing the following to grab the data:

```php
<?php
$json_string_itemData = file_get_contents("ENDPOINT/items.json");
$itemData = json_decode($json_string_itemData);
?>
```

And in the table I am doing the following:

```php
<?php
foreach ($itemData as $item)
{
        echo '<td>' . $item->itemName . '</td>';
}
?>
```

I get the error Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in test.php. The line error is the one mentioned above.

Any idea how I can parse the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add true to make it array

```
$itemData = json_decode($json_string_itemData, true);
```

try this for loop

```
foreach ($itemData as $item)
{
    echo '<td>' . $item['itemDescription'] . '</td>';
}
```

Comment: Hi! Did try that and also didn't help unfortunately. Same error (invalid argument supplied for foreach()).

Comment: try this for loop `foreach ($itemData as $item)
{
        echo '<td>' . $item['itemDescription'] . '</td>';
}`

Comment: I think we figured it out at the exact same time! This works now!